Is the statement "X are X" false if there are no X?
Is any statement of the form "X are X" false if there are no X? For example, is the statement "Unicorns are unicorns" false, because there are no unicorns?

From Conifold:

"X are X" is not a statement since it has a free variable. If you mean "All X are X" (in some domain D, like unicorns), i.e. ∀X∈D (X=X), then it is true even if D is empty according to the modern convention. The convention is that ∀ has no existential import, i.e. it does not entail that things about which the claim is made exist. ∀X∈D (X=X) is an abbreviation of ∀X (X∈D → X=X). If D is empty then X∈D is always false and the implication is always vacuously true, hence the convention.


+1. Very well answered.

Maybe I'm missing a deeper philosophical perspective on this question but here's my understanding and response to your question. I will be answering using a self-answering Socratic method
Questions:

Is any statement of the form "X are X" false if X does not exist?
Is the statement "Unicorns are Unicorns" false if Unicorns do not exist?

Q. Does a Unicorn exist?
A. Well, what is a Unicorn?
Q. A Unicorn is a horse with a horn on it's head. think of a unicorn lol
A. Hmmm alright, What does it mean for something to exist?
Q. For something "to exist" it must have a real being whether spiritual or material. (Webster)
A. Alright... So do Unicorns have material being?
Q. No, Unicorns do not have material being.
A. How about spiritual or conceptual being?
Q. Well I suppose Unicorns have conceptual being within our minds.
A. Agreed, Therefore, I would consider Unicorns to exist.
Hopefully this thought demonstration helped answer your question. Personally, I believe if you are able to state "X are X" you must have a definition or image of what X is inside your mind, therefore it has conceptual existence, therefore it exists. Existence is separated into 2 categories: Conceptual existence and physical existence. Conceptual existence generally is the human experience or perception of material reality whereas physical existence is the real material reality humans are witnessing.
NOTE This is my worldview, and it is subject to err. Some big names with similar worldviews would be Plato or Aristotle (see their work on forms).
Sources:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exist
